# what is the error when terminal says this, React' must be in scope when using JSX,

Tags: reactjs

Failed to compile.

./src/components/AboutView.js
Line 3:7:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Building routes in react for switching between pages

Comment: which version of react are you using? can you edit and add `AboutView.js` code to the question if possible

Comment: Did you import the React module correctly? eg. `import React from 'react';`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.